# Python code to create JSON with Marathi language Giving Unreadable JSON

Tags: python, json, file, utf-8

I am trying to create JSON file using python code. file is created successfully with English language but not properly working with Marathi Language.
Please check out code:

```
import os
import json

jsonFilePath = "E:/file/"
captchaImgLocation = "E:/file/captchaimg/"

path_to_tesseract = r"C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
image_path = r"E:/file/captchaimg/captcha.png"


x = {
    "FName": "प्रवीण",
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

# the result is a JSON string:
print(y.decode())

completeName = os.path.join(jsonFilePath, "searchResult_Unicode.json")
print(str(completeName))
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
file1.write(str(y))
file1.close()
```

```
O/P on console:
{"FName": "प्रवीण"}
<br>
File created inside folder like this:
b'{"FName": "\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\xa3"}'
```

There is no run time or compile time error but JSON is created with with above format.
Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? The binary you are showing is UTF-8 for ``'{"FName": "प्रवीण"}'``. Since you explicitly encoded ``y`` and know to ``.decode`` it for ``print``, why are you surpsised that looking at the file *without* decoding is weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in the encoding you need and then `json.dump` to it:

```py
import os
import json

data = { "FName": "प्रवीण" }

# Writing human-readable.  Note some text viewers on Windows required UTF-8 w/ BOM
# to *display* correctly.  It's not a problem with writing, but you can use
# encoding='utf-8-sig' to hint to those programs that the file is UTF-8 if
# you see that issue.  MUST use encoding='utf8' to read it back correctly.
with open('out.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)

# Writing non-human-readable for non-ASCII, but others will have few
# problems reading it back into Python because all common encodings are ASCII-compatible.
# Using the default encoding this will work.  I'm being explicit about encoding
# because it is good practice.
with open('out2.json', 'w', encoding='ascii') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=True) # True is the default anyway

# reading either one is the same
with open('out.json', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data2 = json.load(f)

with open('out2.json', encoding='utf8') as f:  # UTF-8 is ASCII-compatible
    data3 = json.load(f)

# Round-tripping test
print(data == data2, data2)
print(data == data3, data3)
```

Output:

```py
True {'FName': 'प्रवीण'}
True {'FName': 'प्रवीण'}
```

out.json (UTF-8-encoded):

```json
{"FName": "प्रवीण"}
```

out2.json (ASCII-encoded):

```json
{"FName": "\u092a\u094d\u0930\u0935\u0940\u0923"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have encoded the JSON string, so you must either open the file in binary mode or decode the JSON before writing to file, so:

```py
file1 = open(completeName, "wb")
file1.write(y)
```

or

```py
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
file1.write(y.decode('utf-8'))
```

Doing

```py
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
file1.write(str(y))
```

writes the *string representation* of the bytes to the file, which always the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your json to be human readable? It's usually bad practice since you would never know what encoding to use.
You can write/read your json files with the json module without worrying about encoding:

```
import json

json_path = "test.json"
x = {"FName": "प्रवीण"}

with open(json_path, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(x, outfile, indent=4)

with open(json_path, "r") as infile:
  print(json.load(infile))
```

Comment: You still need to worry about encoding. When you do `open(json_path, "w")`, you are relying on some platform-dependent encoding – eg. on Windows this often some 8-bit codepage, which may or may not be what you want. IIRC, JSON files have to be encoded with UTF-8 according to the specs.

Comment: You're right but I'm not quite sure where you're getting at. `json.load` in Linux will be able to read a json saved in Windows without specifying the encoding and vice versa. Doesn't mean that no encoding takes place just that it's transparent for the user. Only if you want to edit the json manually (see my question above about human-readable form) will you need to actually *worry* about encoding. Or am I missing something?

Comment: True, with `ensure_ascii=True` chances are very small that there will be encoding/decoding errors (not many platforms have an EBCDIC default encoding, I guess). I'm just quite cautious about using `open()` without the encoding param, since it is (in general) something that *causes* rather than solves encoding trouble.

Comment: Now I understand!